# Why window.load() is working in firefox but not in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I am quite a newbie so bear my lack of knowledge.
Using JQuery I am trying to display the arrays of two xml files in a tree.
The code is pretty simple, here is my html page:

```
window.onload = openXML('xml_files/categories.xml','xml_files/products.xml');

var categories = new Array();
var products = new Array();

function jquery_treeview()
{
var unorderedList= ""; 

console.log(categories.length);

for (i=0; i < categories.length; i++)
    {
        unorderedList += "<li ><span onclick='showCategoryDetails("+i+")'>" + categories[i][1] + "</span><ul><ol type='a'>";
        for (j=0; j < products.length; j++)
        {
            if (categories[i][0] == products[j][2]){
            unorderedList += "<li ><span onclick='showProductDetails("+j+")'>" + products[j][1] +"</span></li>";}
        }
        unorderedList += "</ul></li>";
    }

    var jquerytreeview = $(unorderedList).appendTo("#treeViewRight");
    $("#treeViewRight").treeview({
        add: jquerytreeview
    });

}

function showCategoryDetails(index)
{
var details = "Category: " + categories[index][1]+  "\n"  + "Description: " + categories[index][2];
alert(details);
}

function showProductDetails(index)
{
var details = "Product: " + products[index][1] + "\n" + "Price: " + products[index][4]+ "\n" + "Quantity per Unit: " + products[index][3];
alert(details);
}

function openXML(XMLcategory, XMLproduct)
{
var getCategory, getProduct;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    getCategory=new XMLHttpRequest();
    getProduct=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

getCategory.onreadystatechange=function()
{

    if (getCategory.readyState == 4 && getCategory.status == 200)
    {
        category = getCategory.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Categories");

        for (i=0; i < category.length; i++)
        {
            var categoryArray = new Array();
            count=0;
            categoryArray[count++]=category[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            categoryArray[count++]=category[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            categoryArray[count++]=category[i].getElementsByTagName("Description")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            categories[i]=categoryArray;

        }
    }
}


getProduct.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (getProduct.readyState == 4 && getProduct.status == 200)
    {
        product = getProduct.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Products");
        for (i=0; i < product.length; i++)
        {
            var productArray = new Array();
            count=0;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("ProductID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("ProductName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("QuantityPerUnit")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("UnitPrice")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            products[i]=productArray;
        }   
    }
}

getCategory.open("GET", XMLcategory, true);
getCategory.send();
getProduct.open("GET", XMLproduct, true);
getProduct.send();
}
```

The file jquery.treeview.js is downloaded [from here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/)

My problem is that it is working on Firefox(even though I have to clear the history every time i reload), but it is not working on Chrome or IE. I hope someone could help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition. You have three asynchronous actions, two that fetch the data, and one that displays the tree view.

If the action that displays the tree view doesn't happen to be last, it doesn't have the data needed to show the tree view.

You should show the tree view when both actions that fetch the data has completed. You can check at the end of each the `readystatechange` handlers if the other handler has already completed.

When you want to show the tree view, you need to wait for the document to load if it hasn't already. Using the `ready` event in jQuery will solve that, as it will wait for the document to load if it hasn't, and call the function immediately if the document already is loaded.

```
function showTreeView() {
  $(document).ready(jquery_treeview);
}

getCategory.onreadystatechange=function()
{

    if (getCategory.readyState == 4 && getCategory.status == 200)
    {
        category = getCategory.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Categories");

        for (i=0; i < category.length; i++)
        {
            var categoryArray = new Array();
            count=0;
            categoryArray[count++]=category[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            categoryArray[count++]=category[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            categoryArray[count++]=category[i].getElementsByTagName("Description")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            categories[i]=categoryArray;

        }
        if (products.length) showTreeView();
    }
}


getProduct.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (getProduct.readyState == 4 && getProduct.status == 200)
    {
        product = getProduct.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Products");
        for (i=0; i < product.length; i++)
        {
            var productArray = new Array();
            count=0;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("ProductID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("ProductName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("CategoryID")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("QuantityPerUnit")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            productArray[count++]=product[i].getElementsByTagName("UnitPrice")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            products[i]=productArray;
        }
        if (categories.length) showTreeView();
    }
}
```

---

It seems like you try to use the `load` event for the `openXML` function also. That wouldn't have worked, as it would have been overwritten by the `jquery_treeview` reference before the event could happen. However, you are not setting the `openXML` function to be the event handler for the event, you are calling the function and setting the return value as event handler, and as the function doesn't return a function, that does nothing.

You don't need to wait for the `load` event before you start loading the data, just call the method directly:

```
openXML('xml_files/categories.xml','xml_files/products.xml');
```

Comment: wow, thank you for the explanation, even if not everything is clear to me, I need to do a bit more research and studies. I'll try to add your solution and see how I go with it.

Comment: thank you very much. It is working fine. I'll study a bit more your answer to make sure I understand it properly. I am still a bit confused on the part 'you are not setting the openXML function to be the event handler for the event, you are calling the function and setting the return value as event handler, and as the function doesn't return a function, that does nothing'. If you have time could you advice me on where I could find more information on this matter?

Comment: @mikey: To set a function as an event handler you would use `window.onload = theFunction;`, not `window.onload = theFunction();`. The parentheses makes it a function call, so the function would be called and the return value would be assigned to the property, instead of assigning the function reference to the property. To call a function with parameters as event handler you would wrap the function call in a function expression so that you get a function reference to assign to the property: `window.onload = function(){ theFunction(param1, param2); };`.